# MySQL цикл в триггере

Tags: mysql, циклы, триггеры-sql

MySQL (5.7)

На сайте вопросов и ответов есть таблица вопросов `questions`, у неё имеются два триггера срабатывающие при удалении записей, триггеры - `del_quest_before` и `del_quest_after` .

Первый триггер срабатывает **перед** удалением и содержит следующий код:

del_quest_before

```
BEGIN
    SET @qid = OLD.id;
    SET @uid_answ = (SELECT uid FROM answers WHERE qid = @qid);
END
```

@qid - ид удаляемого вопроса, @uid_answ - ид пользователей, которые оставляли ответы к удаляемому вопросу; дело в том, что при удалении вопроса, каскадно по ключу удалятся и ответы, которые он содержит, и мне нужно пересчитать счетчики количества ответов у пользователей. Поэтому перед удалением я делаю выборку пользователей, которые отвечали на вопрос и помещаю её в переменную @uid_answ.

Второй триггер срабатывает **после** удаления вопроса, и я хочу чтобы он выполнил цикл по @uid_answ и для каждого пользователя пересчитал счетчики, должно быть что-то вроде:

```
BEGIN
    ЦИКЛ ПО @uid_answ
        @uid_answ_elem = @uid_answ[0];
        CALL recalc_cnt_users_answ(@uid_answ_elem);
    КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА
END
```

Процедура `recalc_cnt_users_answ` пересчитывает счетчики пользователей, она уже написана в неё всего лишь нужно передать ид пользователя, как это сделать? Прошу помогите.

Comment: процедура recalc_cnt_users_answ вообще не нужна. Если вы ведете где то количество ответов, то более логично его было бы одновлять в триггере на вставку/удаление из самой таблицы ответов. и выглядеть они будут буквально +1/-1. А так, как вы хотите не выйдет, если ответов несколько то в переменной будет только один из них. А даже если бы вы как то в переменную поместили список, то  он был бы текстом и его надо было бы разгребать в recalc. Не говоря уже о том, что никто не гарантирует, что переменная установленная в одном триггере будет доступна в другом

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за помощь, проблема в том, что в MySQL 5.7 при каскадном удалении триггеры не срабатывают, срабатывает только триггер первоначальной таблицы в нашем случае questions, а у других таблиц не срабатывает не только у меня, у всех. Переменная установленная в одном триггере ловится в другом, я проверял, но только если установлена через SET.

Comment: @Я хочу передавать в `recalc_cnt_users_answ` не список ид номеров, а каждый ид по отдельности в цикле.

Comment: ну тогда можно в первом случае применить group_concat, что бы в переменной был список через запятую. А во втором триггере аккуратно вырезаем из строки по одному id и вызываем call. Ну или как варинт завести специальную таблицу, в которую первый триггер вставит все id, а второй в курсоре их переберет и удалит из таблицы

Comment: ну и в догонку третий вариант, первый триггер выставляет в таблице users специальный флаг 'ответы требуют пересчета' и второй триггер по этому признаку пересчитывает. как плюс, если мгновенное обновление количеств не требуется можно его делать вообще отдельной фоновой процедурой, периодически пересчитывая необходимых пользователей или делать это в момент получения этого количества

Comment: И четертый вариант, вместо каскадного удаления сделать удаление триггером. Если конечно в этом случае триггера на ответы сработают

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за варианты, я подумаю над каждым. При удалении триггером, также как и при каскадном, тоже не срабатывают, я пробовал.

Comment: Пятый вариант: не использовать пересчет, а скорректировать значения в таблице пользователей запросом вроде `update users u join (select uid, count(1) delta from answers where qid=OLD.qid group by uid) a on a.uid=u.uid set u.cnt=u.cnt-a.delta`

Comment: Спасибо большое, тоже думаю насчет запроса.

Comment: @Mike подскажи пожалуйста, а в более поздних версиях MySQL, ну например версии 8 срабатывают ли триггеры при каскадном удалении?

Comment: @Mike а то бы просто перешел с хостинга на виртуальный сервер, установил бы версию по-выше и не мучился.

Comment: Даже в документации на 8 версию https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html сказано _Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers_ ... так что на MySQL не судьба ...

Answer (score 0):

Что касается SELECT внутри TRIGGER то нужно использовать конструкцию SELECT INTO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474489/not-allowed-to-return-a-resultset-from-a-trigger-mysql